# Android RecyclerView Custom Stacking Scroll

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

So i have this requirement for a custom scroll for a linear layout and i have no idea where to start. The scroll will be like this:

- instead of recyclerView items leave the screen, the top most item will remain fixed, and the items will overlap it when scrolled. So instead of scrolling out of the screen, or scrolling into the screen, they will scroll out from the first card and into the first car.

I would seek for advices with alternatives, as i have relatively short time to do it. I would avoid doing a custom layout manager unless really necessary (its tricky to do so).